# Options for storing and retrieving small objects (node.js), is a database necessary?

Tags: json, node.js, database, object

I am in the process of building my first live node.js web app. It contains a form that accepts data regarding my clients current stock. When submitted, an object is made and saved to an array of current stock. This stock is then permanently displayed on their website until the entry is modified or deleted.

It is unlikely that there will ever be more than 20 objects stored at any time and these will only be updated perhaps once a week. I am not sure if it is necessary to use MongoDB to store these, or whether there could be a simpler more appropriate alternative. Perhaps the objects could be stored to a JSON file instead? Or would this have too big an implication on page load times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially store in a JSON file or even in a cache of sorts such as Redis but I still think MongoDB would be your best bet for a live site.

Storing something in a JSON file is not scalable so if you end up storing a lot more data than originally planned (this often happens) you may find you run out of storage on your server hard drive. Also if you end up scaling and putting your app behind a load balancer, then you will need to make sure there are matching copy's of that JSON file on each server. Further more, it is easy to run into race conditions when updating a JSON file. If two processes are trying to update the file at the same time, you are going to potentially lose data. Technically speaking, JSON file would work but it's not recommended.

Storing in memory (i.e.) Redis has similar implications that the data is only available on that one server. Also the data is not persistent, so if your server restarted for whatever reason, you'd lose what was stored in memory.

For all intents and purposes, MongoDB is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this answers my question perfectly! I am already familiar with mongoDB at a beginner level. I think part of my concern was cost as the tutorials I learnt from suggested using database storage sites such as mlab etc. Is it possible to install mongoDB locally on a server such as AWS ec2?

Comment: I haven't done it personally but I don't see why not

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go with simpler way i.e JSON file use [nedb API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nedb) which is pretty fast as well.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know for sure is test it with a load test. But as you probably read html and js files from the file system when serving web pages anyway, the extra load of reading a few json files shouldn't be a problem.